# What is the best way in bash to find a value in a file for a given row and column

Tags: bash

Given file

```
PRODUCT: COMPANY 1: COMPANY2: COMPANY 3
product1:   #:       #:        #
product2:   #:       #:        #
```

This file contains the prices for different companies and products. What would be the best way in bash to find the product price for a give company?

Comment: I'd use `awk` to do it.

Comment: If at all possible, switch to a normalized data representation, such as a CSV file of "company","product",price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` assuming that each element is separated by tabs.  If it's a group of spaces, you can also use TR to squeeze them.

```
tail -n +2 file | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

This ignores the first line of the file, squeezes the spaces, and then prints the resulting column.  `2` is the second column (Company 1).  You can change the number as needed to correspond to another company, or even use a range of companies.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -v p="$product" c="$company" '
    NR == 1 { for(i=2; i < NF; i++) { if ($i == c) { cn = i; break; } } }
    $1 == p { print $cn; exit; }' filename
```

The first line of the script finds the field number for the given company name, by searching for the name in the heading line. The rest of the script tests the first field for the product name, and then prints the value in the `cn`th field.

This all assumes that there's no whitespace in any of the product or company names. If there is, you need to provide an unambiguous field delimiter.

Comment: there was syntax error when i tried but the following works                  `awk  'NR==1 {c="COMPANY2"; p="product2"} { for(i=2; i < NF; i++) { if ($i == c){ cn = i; break; }}} $1 == p { print $cn; exit; }' prices.txt`, also why do you use NR==1 instead of NR=1?

Comment: That's fine if you want to hard-code the company and product, I assumed they would be in shell variables so you could write a script to handle any given company and product. `NR = 1` is an assignment, `NR == 1` is a comparison; we only want to run that block on the first line, since it contains the list of company names.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you simply need a single value from the file for a relative 'one-time-use' or if you need to have all of the price data available within the script from which you can process values for each company one at a time. In the first case (one shot get price for companyX from productY), a flexible way would be using grep to return the line for productZ and having the price data available in a 4 element array:

```
price=( `grep product1 dat/product.dat` );
echo -e "\n company[1]: ${price[1]}\n company[2]: ${price[2]}\n company[3]: ${price[3]}\n"
```

If on the otherhand you are wanting all values available in a script, then simply read all values into 4 arrays and index off the product array:

```
declare -a product
declare -a company1
declare -a company2
declare -a company3

while read p c1 c2 c3; do
    product+=p
    company1+=c1
    company2+=c2
    company3+=c3
done

echo "company2 price for product120: ${company2[120]}"
```

While this is a terse example, it shows how you can read all prices into arrays within a script, then search for any `productX` within the `product` array and use to corresponding index to access the price for any price for company[1-3]. Whatever suits your need best.